# RxJS, understanding defer

Tags: rxjs

I searched for the usage of `defer` in RxJS but still I don't understand why and when to use it.

As I understand neither Observable methods is fired before someone subscribes to it.

If that's the case then why do we need to wrap an Observable method with `defer`?

[An example](https://doc.ebichu.cc/RxJS/index.html?name=api/core/operators/defer.md)

I'm still wondering why it wrapped Observable with `defer`? Does it make any difference?

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
  return Rx.Observable.return(42);
});

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) { console.log('Next: ' + x); },
  function (err) { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
  function () { console.log('Completed'); } );
```

Comment: This article has some great examples https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875 including the ability to make a retryable promise.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Quite simply, because `Observables` can encapsulate many different types of sources and those sources don't necessarily have to obey that interface. Some like `Promises` always attempt to eagerly compete.

Consider:

```js
var promise = $.get('https://www.google.com');
```

The promise in this case is already executing before any handlers have been connected. If we want this to act more like an `Observable` then we need some way of *deferring* the creation of the promise until there is a subscription.

Hence we use `defer` to create a block that only gets executed when the resulting `Observable` is subscribed to.

```js
Observable.defer(() => $.get('https://www.google.com'));
```

The above will not create the `Promise` until the `Observable` gets subscribed to and will thus behaves much more in line with the standard `Observable` interface.

Comment: @AlexPineda not sure what you mean. `defer` already understands `Promises` so it already implicitly handles them, so you wouldn't need `fromPromise` unless you wanted its use to be explicit.

Comment: I think what he means is that if you do `fromPromise(promise)` the `promise` being passed to `fromPromise` is already executing and the `fromPromise` just returns that promise in an Observable wrapper.  By using `defer`, the promise will not start executing until we subscribe.

Answer (score 25):

It would be easier to understand if we consider using dates.

```
const s1 = of(new Date()); //will capture current date time
const s2 = defer(() => of(new Date())); //will capture date time at the moment of subscription
```

For both observables (s1 and s2) we need to subscribe. But when s1 is subscribed, it will give the date-time at the moment when the constant was set. S2 will give the date-time at the moment of the subscription.

The code above was taken from https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/defer.html

Answer (score 19):

Take for example ([From this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635)):

```
const source = Observable.defer(() => Observable.of(
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
));
```

Why don't just set the `source` Observable to `of(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)`?

Because if we do that the expression `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` will run right away and be available in `source` as a value before we subscribe to `source`.

We want to delay the evaluation of the expression so we wrap `of` in `defer`.  Now the expression `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` will be evaluated when `source` is subscribed to and not any time earlier.

We are wrapping `of(...)` in the `defer` factory function such that the construction of `of(...)` happens when the `source` observable is subscribed to.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the Observable returned by `defer()` will run the provided factory function _every time it is subscribed to_. So, when using just `of(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))`, every subscriber will receive the same random number, which was calculated once up-front. When wrapping that in `defer()`, each subscriber will receive a different random number, calculated at subscribe-time.

Comment: ..or `const source = defer(async () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))`

Answer (score 4):

An example, let's say you want to send a request to a server. You have 2 options.

**Via XmlHttpRequest**

if you do not `subscribe` to an existing *Observable* `Observable.create(fn)` there would not be any network request. It sends the request **only** when you `subscribe`. This is normal and as it should be via Observables. Its the main beauty of it.

**Via Promise** (fetch, rx.fromPromise)

When you use Promises it does not work that way. Whether you subscribed or not, it sends the network requests right away. To fix this, you need to wrap promises in `defer(fn)`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can fully replace `defer` with regular function. But you have to call the function before subscribing.

```
function createObservable() {
    return from(fetch('https://...'));
}

createObservable().subscribe(...);
```

In case of `defer` you only need to pass `createObservable` function to `defer`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to create an observable which **when subscribed to**, it **performs an ajax request**.

If you try the code below, the **ajax request will be performed immediately**,
and after 5 seconds the response object will be printed, which is not what you want.

```
const obs = from(fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')); 
setTimeout(()=>obs.subscribe((resp)=>console.log(resp)), 5000)
```

One solution is to manually create an `Observable` like below.
In this case the ajax response will be performed after 5 seconds (when `subscribe()` is called):

```
let obs = new Observable(observer => {
    from(fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).subscribe(observer)
});
setTimeout(()=>obs.subscribe((resp)=>console.log(resp)), 5000)
```

`defer` achieves the above in a more straightforward way, and also without the need to use `from()` to convert promise to observable:

```
const obs = defer(()=>fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'))
setTimeout(()=>obs.subscribe((resp)=>console.log(resp)), 5000)
```