# How to wait for a promise to resolve and skip intermediate elements in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say that I have a stream (observable) with some elements:

```
--a---b-c---d--
```

If I have a function that takes one of these elements and returns a promise, like a request, and I do a `flatMap` with that function, the resulting response stream will be something like this (upper case letters are the responses):

```
--a---b-c---d--
----A----B---CD
```

But that means that the request for `c` will start before the request for `b` ends. Suppose that I want to **avoid the request for `c`** to be performed and to have this as a result:

```
--a---b-c---d--
----A----B----D
```

How should I approach this problem?

---

In the following code, I have a stream that emits after 1, 2, 4 and 7 seconds. I have a `request` function that takes two seconds to complete. I want the function to be called only with 1, 4 and 7 (not with 2, because the request for 1 hasn't finished yet).

```
const Rx = require('rx');

const logNext      = x => console.log(new Date(), 'Next:', x);
const logError     = x => console.log(new Date(), 'Error:', x);
const logCompleted = () => console.log(new Date(), 'Completed.');

Rx.Observable.fromArray([1, 2, 4, 7])
  .flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.of(x).delay(x * 1000))
  .flatMapFirst(request)
  .subscribe(logNext, logError, logCompleted);


function request(x) {
  console.log(`Starting request with ${x}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        console.log(`Finishing request with ${x}`);
        resolve(x)
      },
      2000
    );
  })
}
```

`flatMapFirst` produces the correct response stream, but I want to avoid the side-effects produced by calling `request(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to use [`flatMapFirst`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmapfirst.md) if you use rxjs v4. I could not ascertain that the operator exist in rxjs v5. From the documentation:

> The flatMapFirst operator is similar to the flatMap and concatMap
>   methods described above, however, rather than emitting all of the
>   items emitted by all of the Observables that the operator generates by
>   transforming items from the source Observable, flatMapFirst instead
>   propagates the first Observable exclusively until it completes before
>   it begins subscribes to the next Observable. Observables that come
>   before the current Observable completes will be dropped and will not
>   propagate.

Code could be like this :

```
source$.flatMapFirst(makeRequest)
```

What will happen here is that incoming `b` will lead to the creation of `makeRequest(b)`, and the same for `c`. However,  `makeRequest(c)` wont ever be subscribed to, meaning the effects it might include in its implementation wont be performed.

If `makeRequest` itself (i.e. the function, not the observable `makeRequest(x)` is actually doing some effects to create its observable output, and you want to prevent that, then you can use `defer` :

```
source$.flatMapFirst(x => Rx.Observable.defer(() => makeRequest(x)))
```

You can also review the previous following answers for more examples of use of `defer` :

- [What's the difference between two Observables if one is created by defer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447469/whats-the-difference-between-two-observables-if-one-is-created-by-defer/37448607#37448607)
- [Rxjs, understanding defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764578/rxjs-understanding-defer)

Comment: Yep, and if you are using RxJS 5, `flatMapFirst` has been [renamed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed) to [`exhaustMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap).

Comment: Sorry, while this is very helpful, I forgot to mention that I want to avoid the function to be called altogether. Is that possible? I'll update the question to include that.

Comment: What do you mean by avoid the function to be called altogether? You would need to post some code, but in principle, as your observable is not subscribed, nothing is executed. Though in some case one can execute the request, and only the response is put in an observable, in which case you can use `defer` to defer execution of the request, at subscription time. If you post some code, I can explain this much more clearly