# What rxjs operator is like concatmap but waits for each request before firing the next?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

For example let's say I want to make some api calls.  The api I'm dealing with is prone to race conditions so if I make 3 api calls at the same time updating the same piece of data on the server, it could lose some of the data.

Therefore I want to queue up my requests and then fire one off wait for the response to come back before firing the next request.

Basically I need something like concatMap but the problem with concatMap is that it fires all the requests at the same time.  I need concatMap to just wait before firing off the next request.  I'm using rxjs 5.

Here's a plunker using angular2 where you can click buttons.  When you click 1 sec button an observable will get created that returns after 1 second.  There's 2 sec and 3 sec buttons.

https://plnkr.co/edit/6F4JrVueQX8PjPinZqIk?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Wait:</h2>

      <button (click)="start(1)">1 sec</button>
      <button (click)="start(2)">2 sec</button>
      <button (click)="start(3)">3 sec</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {


  constructor() {
  }

  start(wait) {

    const waitSecs = parseInt(wait) * 1000;

    of('clicked').delay(waitSecs).subscribe(
      val => console.log(wait)  
    )

    // Expected behavior:
    // I click 3 sec, 2 sec, and 1 sec right after another.  Then 
    // the console log should output 3, 2, 1.  Right now it's 
    // outputting 1, 2, 3.

  }
}
```

My ideal behavior with this app would be after I click 3 sec, 2 sec, and 1 sec right after another.  Then the console should output 3, 2, 1.  Right now it's 
outputting 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Just curious,you said: " problem with concatMap is that it fires all the requests at the same time.". however the doc says they all are synchronized. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to have only request executing you can use the [`mergeMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) operator with the `concurrency` set to 1. Note that this will mean that to-be-send items will queue up inside your mergeMap operator which can lead to memory issues.

```js
Rx.Observable.from([3,5,2,1])
  .mergeMap(
    i => {
      return Rx.Observable.of(i)
        .do(i => console.log(`starting request for ${i}`))
        .delay(1000)
        .do(null,null, () => console.log(`finished request for ${i}`));
    },
    null,
    1 /* concurrency limited to 1 */
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(`received value: ${val}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works, I updated my plunker and I no longer get the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/EtC8czwAzhRaMEmrTG0s?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You should post some code. `concatMap` should work for your use case. If you observe firing before subscription, it means you need to use `defer` operator to have the firing at subscription time but without code samples it is hard to say more.

Useful links from past questions :

- [How to start second observable *only* after first is *completely* done in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720112/how-to-start-second-observable-only-after-first-is-completely-done-in-rxjs/33724197#33724197)
- [Rx.js wait for callback to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093370/rx-js-wait-for-callback-to-complete/34098135#34098135)
- [Rxjs, understanding defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764578/rxjs-understanding-defer)

Comment: I posted a plunker with my issue.