# rxjs switchMap cache the obsolete result and do not create new stream

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, switchmap

```
const s1$ = of(Math.random())
const s2$ = ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5`)
const s3$ = from(fetch(`https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5`))
const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click')
click$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => s1$)
).subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

I was confused by the code above and can not reason about them properly.
In the first case(`s1$`), the same result is received every time, it LOOKs fine to me even though I can not understand why `switchMap` do not start a new stream each time. OK, it is fine

The really wired thing happen when you run `s2$` and `s3$`, the looks equivalent, right? WRONG!!! the behaviours are completely different if you try them out!

The result of `s3$` is cached somehow, i.e. if you open the network panel, you will see the http request was send only ONCE. In comparison, the http request is sent each time for `s2$`

My problem is that I can not use something like `ajax` from `rx` directly because the http request is hidden a third-party library, The solution I can come up with is to use inline stream, i.e. create new stream every time

```
click$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => from(fetch(`https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5`)))
).subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

So, how exactly I can explain such behaviour and what is the correct to handle this situation?

Comment: where can one find your full code? What is ajax? Are you behind a service worker? You ask a particular question, but you don't provide a way to test the behavior you describe. Please create a code snippet that reproduces the issue (which can be used to prove what you say and to further debug it), put all relevant code in there and update the question

Comment: `switchMap` doesn't cache anything.

Comment: @Guichi Including me in this comment like that unfortunately will send me a notification. But if you have a question about my answer, you can just leave a comment there.

Comment: @Guichi I am not pretending to be `rxjs` expert in any meaning. I am just one of those who tries to answer your question. All I ask is being nice to ones you ask help from. Unlike @Yoshi you did not provide a running code, what you did is posted some **partial** code as is. I read this as "here is something, I don't care how you answer this". And you made @Yoshi to work for you. I would also call the latest comment as not respectful. However I hope you got your answer.

Comment: @Yoshi you answer is pretty useful, I am looking into the highly related thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764578/rxjs-understanding-defer. I can understand the problem of my code is `too eager` and only run once. Still can not fully understand how `defer` do the magic. I think it is the different between javascript object and function. function can be called over and over again while object can not

Comment: @Guchi `defer` simply *wraps* a function (it's only argument) to be called *later*. In the context it's also a stream and as such can be subscribed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you actually execute `Math.random` and `fetch` while setting up your test case.

```
// calling Math.random() => using the return value
const s1$ = of(Math.random())

// calling fetch => using the return value (a promise)
const s3$ = from(fetch(`https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5`))
```

Another is that `fetch` returns a promise, which resolves only once. `from(<promise>)` then does not need to re-execute the ajax call, it will simply emit the resolved value.

Whereas `ajax.getJSON` returns a stream which re-executes every time.

If you wrap the test-streams with `defer` you get more intuitive behavior.

```js
const { of, defer, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { ajax }                 = rxjs.ajax;
const { switchMap }            = rxjs.operators;

// defer Math.random()
const s1$ = defer(() => of(Math.random()));

// no defer needed here (already a stream)
const s2$ = ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5');

// defer `fetch`, but `from` is not needed, as a promise is sufficient
const s3$ = defer(() => fetch('https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5'));

const t1$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('s1'), 'click').pipe(switchMap(() => s1$));
const t2$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('s2'), 'click').pipe(switchMap(() => s2$));
const t3$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('s3'), 'click').pipe(switchMap(() => s3$));

t1$.subscribe(console.log);
t2$.subscribe(console.log);
t3$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>

<button id="s1">test random</button>
<button id="s2">test ajax</button>
<button id="s3">test fetch</button>
```

Comment: `defer` is exactly what I expect even before I  realise the existence of it. My initial solution is using a function or inline the stream just to create a new instance rather than reuse the old one. Now, I think `defer` works the same way somehow